# Ensure my profit margin, discounts provided, markup asked.

Tags: arithmetic, economics

My mathematical problem :

I would like to know the Mark Up percentage that I need to add based on the below data.

**Given :**

- Turnover  = 100€
- Profit Margin (desired) = 20%
- Discount 1 = 30% 
  *100% of my turnover get 30% discount*
- Discount 2 = 5% 
  *30% of my turnover get 5% discount (Group A)*
- Discount 3 = 6% 
  *50% of my turnover get 6% discount (Group B)*
- Discount 4 = 5% 
  *20% of my turnover get 5% discount (Group C)*

*Discount Policy :*
A 30% discount set to all of my clients, 6% discount if someone belongs to Group A, 5% discount if someone belongs to Group B and 6% discount if someone belongs to Group C. Note that someone could belong to more than one groups.

**Desiderata :**

Mark up (%) = ?

Answer (score 0):

Your words in policy disagree with the bullets, assuming policy wording is correct.

You have to explain if the discounts are additive or multiplicative, i.e. a person from group A gets $30\%$ and $6\%$ so is it $36\%$ total discount or he pays $0.7 \cdot 0.95 = 0.665$, a $33.5\%$ discount. Once you get it, do the following:

- For each group, compute the fraction $f_a,f_b,f_c$ they would pay for your product
- If turnover percent per group is $t_a, t_b, t_c$, the total return from group $A$ is $f_a \cdot t_a$. What is the total return from the entire policy?
- Since you want $20\%$ profit from $100$, how much gross sales do you want to actually make after all sales are finished?
- Finally, markup percentage $m$ is used to make the total generated sales equal the desired sales gross amount. Can you write down a linear equation for $m$ and solve it?